# what will be the DC component of this function?

Tags: signal-analysis, fourier, fourier-series

[image]

My answer is that the signal can be splitted into 2 regions, and cancel out the negative and positive areas under the integral, based on the definition

[image]

Needed some validation on this analysis

Thanks..

Update -1 (based on comments)
[image]

Comment: Please learn how to write equations using $\LaTeX$.  That makes it easier for me to copy these equations for use in my answer.

Comment: All four of your equations in the edit neglect the $x$ offset. For example, (1) should be $y = 9-2x$ so that $x=-3$ yields $y=3$. Closing until you do as robert suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Your analysis is wrong; it would only be right if $f(x) = -f(-x)$, but that's not the case at all here.

However, you can decompose your function into two functions that you add to get $f(x)$, one of which that *does* fulfill this requirement, and the other being especially easy to find the DC component of.

OK, then you'd have two functions, which sum up to be your $f(x)$, of which you know the DC component. Now, you need to sit down with your knowledge on the Fourier transform and think about how you can derive the DC component of the sum of two functions from the DC components of the individual functions.

The way this homework is structured, you're at least expected to write down *why* you can do what you're doing there when determining the sum function's DC component, based on properties of the Fourier transform.

Comment: I updated based on your comment like decomposing and combining to form f(x), and used general form to find the coefficient, but I still get 0, could you please check my update and validate my solution.

Comment: I don't really understand what you're doing there, but in my answer I explicitly said it was easy to find the DC offset of the other function; there's literally no math to be done on the actual slopes of the function, you're trying to do that too "schema" and not with enough "look at it and think" :)  So you must have taken a strange decomposition of your function. Look at the first sentence of my answer. **HOW** must you modify your $f(x)$ such that $f(x) = -f(-x)$?

Comment: Ok, so if the function is around 2.5 then it will be anti-symmetric and follows the condition,.